# Grab existing build in gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Lets say I have developed a framework in java and tested it on develop branch now I want to merge my changes to master but I dont want to build from scratch and use the build I have used on develop and then upload it to some production environment(in my case jfrog artifactory). So the question is how can gradle check if build already exists while being on master and use this build to upload to my artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better develop version control from Git, with BASH or directly on Github, when we are dealing with branches in AS we should pay attention to the creation of local and remote branches, on the issue of inserting only what was changed, Github takes care of that part with Merge, in addition, before committing the changes or the pull request you will have the changes that each file will receive, such as a "version history".

Comment: I know and I would personally prefer dealing with it using Git and BASH but the thing is there is already deployment process via gradle and I have to do something over gradle.